# how to concat hours and minutes at a time in Datetime using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

i have an application which it run specifically based on given time to that application, how do i pass the parameter through App.config,

**Ex: My service should run every day 9 clock**

```
datetime Runtime = datetime.today.Addhours(9);
```

the above line will help the service to specifically on that time, now i need to set my service to run by 9:30 , how do i pass the information to Runtime.

i have tried below way it was not accepted

```
ex 1) datetime Runtime = datetime.today.Addhours(9) + datetime.today.Addminutes(30);

ex 2) datetime Runtime = datetime.today.Addhours(9);
               Runtime = datetime.today.Addminutes(30);
```

Comment: Got it answer thank you all, datetime Runtime = datetime.today.Addhours(9).Addminutes(30);

Comment: I'm glad you've got an answer that helps you, but in future please post real code - the code you've prevented wouldn't have compiled as a number of characters are lower case when they should be upper case.

Comment: @JonSkeet noted and i will do the same, many thanks for suggestion i will follow your words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(30)
```

`AddHours` gives you another `DateTime`, so you can call the exact same methods you can call on `DateTime.Today`.

You can also add a `TimeSpan`, though:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse("9:30");
DateTime d = DateTime.Today + t;
```

This would have the benefit that you don't have to separate hours and minutes in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Use them together like:

```
DateTime Runtime = DateTime.Today.Addhours(9).AddMinutes(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
datetime newTime = datetime.today.Addhours(9).Addminutes(30);
```